# How to prescale HFPERCLK in EFR32FG14

Tags: embedded

from the reference manual we have the formula shown bellow.
We need to divide HFPERCLK which is 2MHz by 20 to get 100Khz clk.
From I2C_CTRL we have CLHR bitfield but as you can see bellow its not defining exactly N_low and N_high but the ratio of between them.
how do i define them exactly?
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't define them, they are already defined for you.

In fact, while it looks like they are ratios, they are the actual Nlow and Nhigh numbers.

For Standard Mode I2C, duty of 50%:50% or 1:1 is needed to reach maximum speed of 100kHz.

For Fast Mode I2C, duty of 16:9 is needed to reach maximum speed of 400kHz.
Since the MCU cannot do 16:9 but 6:3 it cannot reach maximum speed of 400kHz with the slowest rise time allowed by the I2C specs.

Comment: Hello Just me, So if i unerstand correctly if i define  I2Cn_CLKDIV to be 1.then by the formula 
(N_high+N_low)*(1+1)+8 needs to be 20 in order to convert 2Mhz into 100Khz.
so (N_high+N_low) has to be 6. but there is no 3:3 option in the CLHR .You said its not a ratio but the real numbers.
So i need to look for N_high+N_low 1:5 2:4 3:3 there are no such options.
Where did i go wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You are absoutely right; there is no option to end up with divisor to be exactly 20, so I2C clock speed of exactly 100 kHz is impossible if the peripheral clock is 2 MHz. You must use what you have.